# Is there a way to support HTML5 video tag on non HTML5 compliant browsers?

Tags: android, html

I am working on HTML5 these days and facing problem in HTML5 video tag. Please help me with suitable answers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: video tag only support in HTML5 . use flash video player as alternative if you can use Flash

Answer (score 0):

You should use HTML5 Shiv for browsers which don't support HTML5 tags. HTML5 Shiv adds all your necessary tags to the browser. You should use html5boilerplate to solve these issues.